# Stuck using HAVING at MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am always using WHERE clause instead of HAVING, but in this case, I am using alias.. which is HAVING CLAUSE is used instead of WHERE..

here my query

```
Select 
      ID, 
      post_date, 
      post_date_gmt, 
      post_content, 
      post_title,
      post_status, 
      post_name, 
      post_type,
      max(case when meta_key = 'ctg' then meta_value end) as category,
      max(case when meta_key = 'qlty' then meta_value end) as quality
   from 
      get_movies
   where 
          post_status = 'publish' 
      and post_type = 'movies' 
      and meta_key in ('ctg','qlty') 
      and post_title like '%a%' 
       OR *CATEGORY LIKE '%a%'*
    group by 
      ID, 
      post_date, 
      post_date_gmt, 
      post_content, 
      post_title,
      post_status, 
      post_name, 
      post_type 
   order by 
      ID desc
```

I need can search at field alias as a category.. **CATEGORY LIKE '%a%'** this is possible for what I want?

*ADDITIONAL INFORMATION FROM ANSWER*

@Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

**[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'category' in 'where clause'**

here the table if u never saw wordpress table

```
post_id | post_title       | meta_key     | meta_value
19      | Example Title1   | ctg          | Horror
19      | Example Title1   | qlty         | HD
20      | Example Title2   | ctg          | Action
20      | Example Title2   | qlty         | HD
```

if im using my query(using alias) , here's the result table

```
post_id | post_title       | category(created from alias meta_key)     | quality
19      | Example Title1   | Horror                                    | HD
```

and in this case, i need query for field category , which is created from meta_key...

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. What is your problem? You want to use HAVING clause?

Comment: *"I am always using `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING`"* -- `WHERE` and `HAVING` are not interchangeable. They operate on different levels. `WHERE` filters rows, the `HAVING` conditions apply to aggregate values computed for groups.

Comment: The query doesn't make any sense. What's the point of grouping by `ID`? Do you have more than one entry with a given `ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am always using `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING`

`WHERE` and `HAVING` are not interchangeable. They operate on different levels. `WHERE` filters rows, the `HAVING` conditions apply to aggregate values computed for groups.

`WHERE` is not able to evaluate a condition that involves the `category` alias because it aliases a value computed after grouping. The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before grouping.

The `CATEGORY LIKE '%a%'` condition must stay in the `HAVING` clause (after `GROUP BY`).

**Your `WHERE` clause is wrong.** The last two conditions (those joined by `OR`) should be placed inside parentheses because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. As it is now, the query selects all the rows that match the category, no matter the values of the other fields (`post_status`, `post_type` etc).

Because of the `OR` you need to move both conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  post_date, 
  post_date_gmt, 
  post_content, 
  post_title,
  post_status, 
  post_name, 
  post_type,
  max(case when meta_key = 'ctg' then meta_value end) as category,
  max(case when meta_key = 'qlty' then meta_value end) as quality
FROM
  get_movies
WHERE 
      post_status = 'publish' 
  and post_type = 'movies' 
  and meta_key in ('ctg','qlty') 
GROUP BY
  ID, 
  post_date, 
  post_date_gmt, 
  post_content, 
  post_title,
  post_status, 
  post_name, 
  post_type 
HAVING
     post_title like '%a%' 
  or category like '%a%'
ORDER BY
  ID desc
```

Read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for more information about the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and how it is executed.

Comment: I hope it works. You can imagine I wasn't able to test it.

Comment: @Edofx .. No this isn't what you need, you should work from the base tables and then refactor your `get_movies` view. This'll work, but it's a patch over problems that you have created for yourself.

Comment: I completely agree with @arth.

Comment: @axiac, it does answer the immediate question and contains some good information about the WHERE and HAVING clauses, however so I'll give you a plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the aliased column name in the where, but have to explicitly include the same reference context

```
where ... (other criteria) ...
   OR ( meta_key = 'ctg' AND meta_value like '%a%' )
```

So, for all your other meta-data values that are NOT of the category qualfier, it ignores, but when it DOES hit, applies the like as well.

Comment: You can use a SELECT alias in a HAVING clause n MySQL, just not a WHERE clause.

Comment: @Arth, you are correct, I just have very FEW times I actually use a HAVING clause.  It makes sense as the result is already computed, aggregated, etc and proper column IS available for comparison before keep / throw away.  Thanks and remove having from answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a WHERE clause to an aliased column, but I'd suggest your problem lies more with your data structure.

Looks like you have a bit of a crazy set up where you are duplicating a whole bunch of information (all your `GROUP BY` columns) just to allow a flexible meta column.

Why not separate the meta stuff out into a separate table `post_meta`, with the columns `post_id`, `key`, `value`.

Then you can run the following query:

```
   SELECT p.ID, 
          p.post_date, 
          p.post_date_gmt, 
          p.post_content, 
          p.post_title,
          p.post_status, 
          p.post_name, 
          p.post_type,
          pc.value as category,
          pq.value as quality
     FROM get_movies p
LEFT JOIN post_meta pc /* Category Join */
       ON pc.post_id = p.ID
      AND pc.key = 'ctg'
LEFT JOIN post_meta pq /* Quality Join  */
       ON pq.post_id = p.ID
      AND pq.key = 'qlty'
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
      AND p.post_type = 'movies' 
      AND (p.post_title LIKE '%a%' OR pc.value LIKE '%a%')
 ORDER BY p.ID desc
```

Comment: `**LEFT JOIN post_meta pc /* Category Join */*`

post_meta ? u mean join from table and table ? wp_posts and wp_postmeta? im already create view for this.. thats why called 'get_movies'

Comment: @Edofx Well, I'd probably include that information in the question and tag it as wordpress.. sounds like your view `get_movies` needs a refactor if it's returning duplicated tuples. I'd start with the base tables, and go from there, you can always add views back in later.